# How to write a python script to find the intersection between two files and append original file

Tags: python, intersection

I am new to programming but have the following problem to solve. I wish to find the intersection of two files.

For example, FILE 1:

```
> scaffold1          0        206        transcript_loc.00001      exon 
> scaffold1         262      749       transcript_loc.00001      exon   
> scaffold1         1391    1549     transcript_loc.00001      exon
```

FILE2:

```
scaffold1        517     540     Simple_repeat   
scaffold1        1063    1162    LTR/Gypsy        
scaffold1        1400     1498   LTR
```

I want to call where the two files coordinates intersect, and then append the intersect to File1.

Resultant file:

```
 scaffold1          0        206        transcript_loc.00001      exon    
 scaffold1         262      749       transcript_loc.00001      exon          517     540     Simple_repeat   
 scaffold1         1391    1549     transcript_loc.00001      exon          1400     1498   LTR
```

Any suggestions as to where to start with this would be most welcome. I can find the intersection using BedTools Intersect, but I really want to know how to do this with python.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both files are ordered as in your example then you can find the intersection as you go along reading line by line intelligently from one or both. This is friendlier on memory consumption of your process and doesn't require looping of file2 for each line in file1. This doesn't matter for such small files as your example but will help you when these files are big.

Mind you that I've only taken into account the start and stop columns to match the DNA strands. If other fields also need to be matched this code will not work (but you might be able to adjust it).

More checks (e.g. on lines in the source files) will be needed before you can use it in real life.

**The code:**

```
def read_and_parse_line(fh):
    # It gets the next line,
    #   strip any whitespace from the end,
    #   split it on whitespace into fields.
    return fh.next().rstrip().split()

def append_to_result(result, line):
    (scaffold1, start1, end1, transcript1, type1, start2, end2, comment2) = line
    # Making start and end real integers so you can work with them as such.
    result.append((scaffold1, int(start1), int(end1), transcript1, type1, int(start2), int(end2), comment2))

# These will be our result lines.
result = []
# With makes sure the files are properly closed afterwards.
with open('file1') as file1, open('file2') as file2:
    # Getting the iterator on the files.
    file1 = iter(file1)
    file2 = iter(file2)
    try:
        (scaffold1, start1, end1, transcript1, type1) = read_and_parse_line(file1)
        read_second = True
        while True:
            if read_second:
                try:
                    (scaffold2, start2, end2, comment2) = read_and_parse_line(file2)
                except StopIteration:
                    print("File 2 ended.")
                    # Nothing more in the second file.
                    # Outputting the original line
                    result.append((scaffold1, start1, end1, transcript1, type1, 0, 0, None))
                    # Reading in a new line from the first file.
                    (scaffold1, start1, end1, transcript1, type1) = read_and_parse_line(file1)
            if int(start1) <= int(start2):
                # Second file record starts after the first file record.
                if int(end1) >= int(end2):
                    # And the second file record ends before the first file record.
                    # = MATCH!!!
                    print("We've found a match: [%s-[%s-%s]-%s]" % (start1, start2, end2, end1))
                    # Write the combined line.
                    result.append((scaffold1, start1, end1, transcript1, type1, start2, end2, comment2))
                    ## READ BOTH
                    (scaffold1, start1, end1, transcript1, type1) = read_and_parse_line(file1)
                    read_second = True
                else:
                    # The second file record ends AFTER the first file record.
                    print("No match in second file: [%s-%s]" % (start1, end1))
                    # So writing out the unmodified line.
                    result.append((scaffold1, start1, end1, transcript1, type1, 0, 0, None))
                    ## READ 1
                    (scaffold1, start1, end1, transcript1, type1) = read_and_parse_line(file1)
                    read_second = False
            else:
                # This is thrown away in your example.
                print("No match in the first file for: [%s-%s]" % (start2, end2))
                # Trying the next line in the second file.
                read_second = True
    except StopIteration:
        print("File 1 ended.")
# Printing a clean line after all the logging above.
print("")

# Printing the result to screen.
# I guess you want to do more stuff with the data and not just write it to file.
for line in result:
    # The 8th element being equal to None indicates there was no match.
    if line[7] == None:
        print("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" % line[:5])
    else:    
        print("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" % line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't specify any additional constraints (e.g. the need to do intersection in-place, any requirements in terms of efficiency or optimal speed, the presence of a 'beautiful algorithm', etc.), you can (and should!) use the dumbest possible strategy:

1. **Read the first file line by line**.
2. For each line, get the coordinates. For example, this would be (0, 206) for your first line in `file1`.
3. Before moving on to the next line, check all of `file2` for the first line that has coordinates in the interval you want.

   For instance, if your desired interval is (0, 206), then nothing in
   `file2` has coordinates between that - if your desired interval is
   (262, 749), then the second line with coordinates (517, 540)
   matches.
4. If there is a corresponding line in `file2`, *add* that to your existing line in `file1`.
5. Go back to step 2 until you're done.

---

### The Code

```
path_to_file1 = '<insert path of file1 here>'
path_to_file2 = '<insert path of file2 here>'
path_to_final_output_file = '<insert desired path here>'

# To make the code simpler, I first create a single string that I
# will append each successive line to. At the end, I will just dump
# the whole thing into a new file and call it a day. 

final_output_contents = ''

with open(path_to_file1, 'r') as file1:
     
    for line in file1:

    # split '> scaffold1          0        206        transcript_ loc.00001      exon '
    # into ['>', 'scaffold1', '0', '206', 'transcript_loc.00001', 'exon']
    # then take the third and fourth elements respectively to get 
    # your interval

        # `.split()` will break the string up by whitespace, [2:4]
        # is Python's slice notation, basically a clever way to select
        # elements in an array. This will return 0, 206 for the first 
        # line in the example.

        interval_start, interval_end = line.split()[2:4]

        # now read through the entirety of `file2`. Do the same
        # as before: split each line, get the coordinates, and this time
        # check if they meet the condition that they are in the interval

        with open(path_to_file2, 'r') as file2:
            for other_line in file2:

                first_coordinate, second_coordinate = other_line.split()[1:3]

                # `int()` converts its arguments into integers - we need it
                # because 
                if (int(interval_start) < int(first_coordinate) and 
                    int(interval_end) > int(second_coordinate)):

                    # this is just a fancy way of adding `line` and 
                    # the last three elements of `other_line` together
                    line += '\t'.join(other_line.split()[-3:])

                    # break the `for other_line in file2` loop! 
                    break

        # add this line to your final file, making sure to add
        # a newline character '\n' so your text editor will insert
        # an appropriate line break.

        final_output_contents += line + '\n'

# now dump the contents to your file
with open(path_to_final_output_file, 'w') as final_output_file:
    final_output_file.write(final_output_contents)
```